# Input events not working in Jquery Mobile and PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

This works in JSFiddle (see at http://jsfiddle.net/MygJC/4/) but does not want to fire in my JQuery Mobile (1.2.1) and Phonegap (Cordova 2.3) app:

```
<div id='cont-sum-fields'>
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-1" />
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-2" />
    <input type="number" id="cont-sum-3" />
    <input type="number" id="total-cont-sum" disabled />
```

```
$('div#cont-sum-fields').on('change', 'input', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).parent().children('input[id^="cont-sum"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).parent().children('#total-cont-sum').val(total);
});
```

Any idea why?

**Edit**

This seems to be a wider problem relating to having JQuery event handlers for DOM elements that are inserted dynamically. I am re-triggering a page create after the DOM elements are inserted, but that is not sufficient. investigating further.

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MygJC/7/

Comment: Hi guys, solved. I think the key thing I did not mention was that the wrapper `<div id="cont-sum-fields">` is inserted dynamically, which means that the JQuery event handler can only be attached dynamically when the element has been inserted into the DOM. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer here seems obvious now but it is still interesting to note. Thanks to Gajores for the hint. If you have dynamic content inserted into the DOM **and a JQuery `on()` event handler is attached to a dynamic element**, you must register the event handlers dynamically after insertion. If the JQuery `on()` event handler is attached to a static DOM element **but refers to a dynamic element inside** it can be attached as the DOM is loaded, even if the dynamic element is not there.

I must say, this is the type of stuff that the documentation does not always explain well to the intermediate user.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is working in a jsFiddle example, you didn't include jQuery Mobile. As soon as you initialize it everything brakes.

To understand why you need to understand how jQuery Mobile styles its form elements. When jQuery Mobile style its content it hides everything and create new custom widget elements. This is why your code is not working any more. Input elements are still there but their structure path is different.

This example will work in your Phonegap app: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/MygJC/6/

```
$('div#cont-sum-fields').on('change', 'input', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#cont-sum-fields').find('input[id^="cont-sum"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") total += parseFloat($(this).val())
    });
    $('#cont-sum-fields').find('#total-cont-sum').val(total);
});
```

This is how your page looks like when jQuery Mobile restyle it:

```
<div id="cont-sum-fields">
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
        <input type="number" id="cont-sum-1" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
        <input type="number" id="cont-sum-2" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c">
        <input type="number" id="cont-sum-3" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c ui-disabled">
        <input type="number" disabled="disabled" id="total-cont-sum" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c mobile-textinput-disabled ui-state-disabled" aria-disabled="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry dude, still not working, even if I just put in an alert for the change event it does not fire.

Comment: Change your change binding to this: $(document).on('change', 'input', function() { , you are probably trying to bind an event before id="cont-sum-fields" is loaded into the DOM.